# Updating ComboBox via setSelectedId() not working in C++ with JUCE?

Tags: c++, combobox, juce

I am struggling to get my `ComboBox` to show a new selection by code.
When creating the box, I use `outputSelector.setSelectedId(1);` which nicely shows the 1st item in the list when the program is “build”.

According to JUCE documentation, `setSelectedId(new ID)` should change the shown item in the `ComboBox`, but somehow that doesn't work.

At certain point, I want the shown output to change via `outputSelector.setSelectedId(outID + 1, juce::dontSendNotification);` after that I change my `midiOutput` via `midiOutput = juce::MidiOutput::openDevice(outputSelector.getSelectedId() - 1);`

The weird thing is, that it opens the correct port and sends a message, but the `ComboBox` isn’t updated. Changing the Notification doesn’t help either.

Below the complete code

I changed the code a bit and added a button for testing. That works if inside the function, but setting it from another function isn't working. Maybe someone has an idea

[code]

```
#pragma once

#include <JuceHeader.h>
inline int outID = 0;


class MyMidiComponent : public juce::Component,
    public juce::MidiInputCallback
    
{
public:
    MyMidiComponent()
    {
         addAndMakeVisible(outputSelector);
        outputSelector.setTextWhenNoChoicesAvailable("No MIDI Outputs Enabled");
        outputSelector.onChange = [this] { midiOutput = juce::MidiOutput::openDevice(outputSelector.getSelectedId() - 1); };
        midiOutputs = juce::MidiOutput::getDevices();
        if (midiOutputs.size() > 0)
        {
            outputSelector.addItemList(midiOutputs, 1);
            outputSelector.setSelectedId(1);
            outputSelector.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            outputSelector.setTextWhenNoChoicesAvailable("No MIDI Outputs Available");
            outputSelector.setEnabled(false);
        }
        juce::MidiOutput::openDevice(outputSelector.getText());
        outputSelector.setBounds(400, 10, 240, 20);

        myButton.setButtonText("Set");
        myButton.setBounds(360, 10, 30, 20);
        myButton.onClick = [this]() { outputSelector.setSelectedId(outID + 1, juce::dontSendNotification); };
        addAndMakeVisible(myButton);
    }

    void sendMidiMessage(int outChannel, int cc0, int cc32, int pc, juce::String outPort)
    {
        outID = 1; // midiOutputs.indexOf(outPort);
        if (outID >= 0)
        {
            outputSelector.setSelectedId(outID + 1, juce::dontSendNotification);
            outputSelector.repaint();
            midiOutput = juce::MidiOutput::openDevice(outputSelector.getSelectedId() - 1);
        }
        if (midiOutput != nullptr)
        {
            juce::MidiMessage msg;
            if (cc0 >= 0)
                msg = juce::MidiMessage::controllerEvent(outChannel, 0, cc0);
            if (cc32 >= 0)
                msg = juce::MidiMessage::controllerEvent(outChannel, 32, cc32);
            if (pc >= 0)
                msg = juce::MidiMessage::programChange(outChannel, pc);
            midiOutput->sendMessageNow(msg);
        }
    }

    ~MyMidiComponent()
    {
        if (midiInput != nullptr)
        {
            midiInput->stop();
            midiInput.reset();
            deviceManager.removeMidiInputDeviceCallback(juce::MidiInput::getAvailableDevices()[inputSelector.getSelectedItemIndex()].identifier, this);
        }
        if (midiOutput != nullptr)
            midiOutput.reset();
    }

    void paint(juce::Graphics& g) override
    {
    }

    void resized() override
    {
    }

    
    // MIDI input callback

    void handleIncomingMidiMessage(juce::MidiInput* source, const juce::MidiMessage& message) override
    {
        midiOutput = juce::MidiOutput::openDevice(outID);
        if (midiOutput != nullptr)
        {
            midiOutput->sendMessageNow(message);
        }
    }

    
private:
    juce::AudioDeviceManager deviceManager;
    int lastInputIndex = 0;
    juce::ComboBox inputSelector, outputSelector;
    std::unique_ptr<juce::MidiInput> midiInput;
    std::unique_ptr<juce::MidiOutput> midiOutput;
    juce::StringArray midiOutputs;
    juce::StringArray midiInputs;
    juce::TextButton myButton;
    

    /** Starts listening to a MIDI input device, enabling it if necessary. */
    void setMidiInput(int index)
    {
        auto list = juce::MidiInput::getAvailableDevices();

        deviceManager.removeMidiInputDeviceCallback(list[lastInputIndex].identifier, this);

        auto newInput = list[index];

        if (!deviceManager.isMidiInputDeviceEnabled(newInput.identifier))
            deviceManager.setMidiInputDeviceEnabled(newInput.identifier, true);

        deviceManager.addMidiInputDeviceCallback(newInput.identifier, this);
        inputSelector.setSelectedId(index + 1, juce::dontSendNotification);

        lastInputIndex = index;
    }


    //==============================================================================
    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR(MyMidiComponent)
};
```

[/code]

Comment: Are you calling outputSelector.setSelectedId() from the main/message thread?

Comment: Hi @RuurdAdema, yes as far I know. Above code is all in the same .h file. In Public as the sendMidiMessage() is called from a different .h file.  Only handleIncomingMidiMessage() is in Private.